# R Shiny --> Create a Boxplot based on SelectInput of Dummy Variables

Tags: r, shiny, dashboard, reactive

I am trying to build an R Shiny dashboard that displays a couple of pages for my exercise data. I am stuck on how to write the code for a dashboard of boxplots displaying the distribution of Calories burned per Trainer.  What I want to happen is to have a selectInput that allows a user to select from a list of Trainers and this selection will update the boxplot.  But, the variable selected will be a dummy variable where I have the selected Trainer boxplot compared against "All other" trainers side by side.

Here is an example of my dataset:

```
VisitNum VisitNumMonth Date       ClassLength Calories AvgHR Location Trainer   Visits_Trainer
1        1             12/15/19   56          602      128   A        Mike      4
2        1             12/16/19   55          610      130   A        Mike      4
3        2             01/04/20   52          550      120   A        Sally     2
4        2             01/05/20   61          575      134   B        Jennie    5
5        2             01/10/20   57          654      133   A        Tim       1
6        2             01/17/20   55          592      119   A        Rachael   1
7        3             02/04/20   50          632      129   B        Jennie    5
8        3             02/22/20   48          630      125   B        Jennie    5
9        3             02/28/20   59          609      136   B        Marshall  6
10       4             03/03/20   53          598      134   A        Mike      4
```

Here is my code:

```
library(RSQLite)
library(sqldf)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)

data=as.data.frame(read_excel("mydata.xlsx",sheet=1))

#Create "Other" value for Trainers with less than 3 visits
data$Trainer2=ifelse(data$Visits_Trainer>=3,data$Trainer,"Other")

#Remove "Other" as possible selection in SelectInput
TrainerChoices=unique(data$Trainer2)
TrainerChoices=TrainerChoices[!TrainerChoices %in% "Other"]

Table1=sqldf("select VisitNum as 'Visit #', Date, Location as 'Studio', Trainer, Calories, AvgHR
             from data
             group by VisitNum, Date, Location, Trainer")


# Define UI for application
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Exercise Data Analysis"),
  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title=""),
    dashboardSidebar(
      sidebarMenu(
        menuItem("All Data",
                 tabName = "AllData",
                 icon=icon("table")
        ),
        menuItem("Trainer Boxplots",
                 tabName = "trainbox",
                 icon=icon("dumbbell")
        ),
        selectInput(inputId = "trainerselect",label="Select a Trainer:",choices=TrainerChoices)

      )
    ),
    dashboardBody(
      tabItems(
        tabItem(
          tabName = "AllData",
          DTOutput("alldata")
            ),


      tabItem(
        tabName = "trainbox",
        plotOutput("trainbox")

      ))
    )
  )
)



# Define server logic 
server <- function(input, output) {
#----------ALL DATA TABLE----------#
  output$alldata=renderDT({
    datatable(Table1,options=list(pageLength=10,
                              lengthMenu=c(10,15,20,25)
    ),rownames = FALSE)
  })

#---------- TRAINER BOXPLOTS ----------#


TrainData=reactive({
  NewDummy=ifelse(data$Trainer2==input$TrainerChoices,input$TrainerChoices,"Other")
  return(NewDummy)


})

output$trainbox=renderPlot({
 plot=ggplot(TrainData(),aes(y=Calories,x=as.factor(NewDummy)))+geom_boxplot(aes(col=as.factor(NewDummy)))
 plot
  })

  }


# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

When I run this code, the All Data tab appears just fine, but I can't get the Trainer Boxplots to show up appropriately.  The page appears with an error that reads:

```
`data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not a logical vector
```

Can someone please help point me in the right direction?  Any help would be appreciated!  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you intended, but perhaps this will be helpful.

First, your `selectInput` in `ui` has an id of `trainerselect`, so you need to access through `input$trainerselect` not `TrainerChoices`.

Your `TrainData` reactive expression will return a character value (a trainer name or "Other"); I assume you want to use `data` for your source of data, not this. `NewDummy` is a local variable in the reactive expression. Perhaps that is what you want from `TrainData()`.

If I'm mistaken/confused, please let me know.

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  #----------ALL DATA TABLE----------#
  output$alldata=renderDT({
    datatable(Table1,options=list(pageLength=10,
                                  lengthMenu=c(10,15,20,25)
    ),rownames = FALSE)
  })

  #---------- TRAINER BOXPLOTS ----------#
  TrainData=reactive({
    NewDummy=ifelse(data$Trainer2==input$trainerselect,input$trainerselect,"Other")
    return(NewDummy)
  })

  output$trainbox=renderPlot({
    NewDummy <- TrainData()
    plot=ggplot(data,aes(y=Calories,x=as.factor(NewDummy)))+
      geom_boxplot(aes(col=as.factor(NewDummy)))
    plot
  })

}
```